# Sitecore : image size when using <img> in rich text

Tags: html, image, sitecore

I know it's possible when writing code to ask sitecore for an image of a specific height and width. If there is one very large/detailed image in sitecore, sitecore will return this resized image ( Instead of using a large image and simply showing in smaller ).

But now i need to insert images into rich text. If i use `<img src="somePath" height="100" width="100">`, will this have the same effect and does sitecore fetch a smaller version of the image ( possibly already in cache ). Or does it send the large image and use pure css to show it as a smaller image ?

Comment: Image in Rich Text are resized server side. if you use the Sitecore image picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sitecore 8 if you add a media library image to the Rich Text field and set the image height and width from the editor (see screenshot), Sitecore will generate image with src like this

```
<img src="/~/media/.....jpg?h=84&w=149" />
```

This means that image will be resized server side by Sitecore before returning to the client browser.

[image]

But if you edit html of the Rich Text content manually and create an image tag like

```
<img src="/~/media/...jpg" width="84" height="149" />`
```

Sitecore will not resize this image on server side for you.

Comment: This is the same for other versions of Sitecore as well.

Comment: Remember that for Sitecore 7.5 & 8, you will also need to hash the url with parameters on. See this post for more info: http://www.seanholmesby.com/images-not-resizing-in-sitecore-7-5-sitecore-8-0/

Comment: @RichardSeal You only need the hash if you are linking directly to media items. Using the Sitecore Controls, MVC Helpers or the insert image in RTE you don't need to worry about the hashes, pipelines handle/add the hashes in automatically.

Comment: Very true - I didn't realize this was just talking about the RTE - I need to get my eyes checked :)